# Rasterizing vector layer (polygon) in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, rasterization, arcgis-10.6

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.

While rasterizing my vector layer, lots of noise creates, I remove most of them by applying different cell sizes and the best one is 45.

[image]

The only problem left is the one showing in the picture with an arrow. There is nothing behind those pixels and I am wondering why a kind of bridge between pixels at the edge are created.

[image]

I tried  Region Group, Set Null, and Nibble tools but it does not help me as it removes most of small pixels which are key for my analysis.

How can I remove those red pixels?

The original vector map is as follows.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the polygon layer have the "bridge" like in the upper screenshot? Could you add a screenshot showing the same Place but with the polygon layer visible instead of raster?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is nothing in the vector layer.

Comment: Can you replace your vector map image with something better. When we click on it to enlarge it to try and see what it is, the resulting image is the same size, so it is very difficult to understand it.